# Apostrophe CMS Editor role "commit" and "submit" functionality

Tags: user-roles, apostrophe

I have set up the Editor role in Groups and assigned it with the permissions shown in the attached image. I then created a user and assigned the user to the Editor group.

Next, I chose a page and assigned it to Editors. So far, so good. However, when I log in as my Editor user and make a change to a page, I don't see the "commit" or "submit" buttons at the bottom of the window (as is seen when logged in as Admin). Also, if I try to submit the page via *Workflow > Manage*, I see both "Submit" and "Commit" although "Commit" doesn't actually commit the changes. I would expect to see [only] "Submit" at the bottom of the window as well as [only] "Submit" in the available selections of the dropdown in the *Workflow > Manage* window.

Needless to say, I'm confused by this odd behavior. Any thoughts or direction would be appreciated. I'm using `apostrophe@2.92.1` and `apostrophe-workflow@2.22.0` .[image: Editor Permissions]

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in an update by the Apostrophe team.